# Python mathematic Calculation

Tags: python, math

```
PCD = int(raw_input("What is PCD?   "))


QOH = int(raw_input("Quantity of holes?   "))


print "radius:   ",
Radius = float(PCD)/2
print Radius


AOS = float(360)/QOH
print "Angle of Seperation:   ",
print AOS

import math as M
def Y_value_1st(a, B):
    a*round(M.degrees(M.sin(B)))

print Y_value_1st(Radius, AOS)
```

this prints none, instead of the intended answer, can anyone help?
I'm new to python

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return value inside the function ;

```
def Y_value_1st(a, B):
    return a*round(M.degrees(M.sin(B)))
```

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer is true you should close the question; click to set this answer as your accepted answer. @user3778839